# Fail Safe Internet connection for home

Tags: networking

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question

So I have a Windows 10  HP laptop

**I have a broadband/cable internet connection** - which I have connected to my laptop using a long (20 meters) cat 6 Ethernet cable ( because I work from the first floor and since WiFi router is in ground floor at times the WiFi strength is not great)

**I also have another Internet connection** ( different ISP) this time from a WiFi dongle.

**Problem:**

I have to give 2 -3 online exam in couple of weeks time and need to ensure that I have a failsafe internet connection - because even a momentary disconnection can end the exam session.

My broadband connection has the best bandwidth close to 30 Mbps, however, the connection is not reliable, and sometimes there are 5-10 minutes internet failures once every hour.

The internet from the WiFi dongle is stable but it has low bandwidth ( due to distance of the transmitting tower from my house) but usually say I manage to get around 2-3 Mbps bandwidth, which is sufficient from exam point of view.

**Requirement:**
So what I need is to use my WiFi internet connection as primary because its a stable and incase the WiFi connectivity drops, I want the wired internet connection to take over immediately .

**Is this possible ?**

I heard of a paid app called "speedify", however since its a paid app and my requirement is only very short , I was wondering if there is any other solution to my problem other than buying this app.

**Note:** I cannot move downstairs because, with the Ethernet connection I have taken care of my broadband signal issue, trouble with broadband is its unexpected ISP downtime.

If I was in any other location the WiFi dongle would have been enough because its capable of giving speed up to 8 Mbps however due to the location of my house, I have to keep the dongle on the roof - that's how dongle is giving me better speed/connectivity - but as you would have realized even this is not foolproof hence my need to rely on both these connections.

Comment: I would connect using ethernet cable while taking the test.

Answer (score 0):

Once you connect to both internet connections you can use the network metrics to "route" your traffic to your preferred connection. (I assume your dongle is installed as a network card).

The one with the lower metric is always used (would be the LAN cable) and will be automatically switched to the other if the connections become unavailable.

To change the metric of a networkcard

- open PowerShell as admin
- show current configuration with `Get-NetIPInterface`

Three columns are important:

- interface name (InterfaceAlias)
- interface index (ifIndex)
- interface metric (InterfaceMetric)

Assuming your cable connection doesn't have a lower metric already, e.g.:

- cable connection has the index 9 and the metric 50
- WLAN connection has the index 10 and the metric 20

Use the following command to e.g. change your cable connection

```
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex 9 -InterfaceMetric 15
```

You can test it by using `tracert google.com` in CMD, you'll see it will use the network card with the lower metric.

**However**, you need to test you online exam software and keep in mind:
Suddenly using a different internet might terminate your connection anyway since your "public internet IP" will suddenly change. But there will be no way around this if you are using separate Internet connections.

Comment: Thanks Albin , the dongle connection is via WiFi , I am not sure if I can share a link to the product but if you google "JIO M2 Wireless Router" you should be able to see the device that I am talking about.

Comment: @Dimitrz Not sure what you mean, I know that the dongle receives WLAN.

Comment: Hi Albin , what I meant is the only way you can connect the dongle transmitted internet is through Wifi , I am not a technical person but I think you can call that WLAN but since its only my home PC there are no other devices connected to the Dongle internet connection

Comment: @Dimitrz Does the dongle show up as a network interface in device manager or in the control panel -> network -> network connections?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this with an app called " Speedify "

Not sure if I can post a link
@ Mods please feel free to delete the link if its against the rules

https://speedify.com/